# Bootstrap 5 carousel Not at top of page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I implemented a bootstrap 5 carousel to my page but the carousel will not line up to the top of the page. There is a big chunk of white space that the carousel will not go on top of.

This is the code for the carousel:

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="../assets/images/peakpx(68).jpg" class=" w-100" alt="rap">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-flex flex-column h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <h2 class="bg-dark bg-opacity-50 py-2 px-4">Fallout Music Co.</h2>
        <p class="bg-dark bg-opacity-50 py-2 px-4">The following images are some of our featured artists for the Hip-Hop & Rap category
          slide.</p>
        <a href="../roots/item1.html" class="btn btn-light px-4 py-2 rounded-0">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="../assets/images/peakpx(54).jpg" class=" w-100" alt="hip">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-flex flex-column h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <h2 class="bg-dark bg-opacity-50 py-2 px-4">Playboi Carti</h2>
        <p class="bg-dark bg-opacity-50 py-2 px-4">Playboi Carti is an american rapper with his top hit being wokeuplikethis ft. Lil Uzi Vert</p>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=playboi+carti&rlz=1CAHUVK_enUS1057&oq=playboi+&aqs=chrome.0.0i355i433i512j46i433i512j69i57j0i131i433i512j0i433i512j0i512j69i61l2.2456j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on" class="btn btn-light px-4 py-2 rounded-0">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="../assets/images/peakpx(52).jpg" class=" w-100" alt="hop">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-flex flex-column h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <h2 class="bg-dark bg-opacity-50 py-2 px-4">XXXTentacion</h2>
        <p class="bg-dark bg-opacity-50 py-2 px-4">XX is a deceased rapper that left more than a legend or legacy behind. His music continues to impact all his listeners to this day.</p>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/search?gs_ssp=eJzj4tVP1zc0TDZLqbCoNI43YPTiqaioKEnNK0lMzszPAwCEGQmr&q=xxxtentacion&rlz=1CAHUVK_enUS1057&oq=xx&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j46i131i433i512j0i131i433i512j0i512j0i131i433i512j69i60l3.1922j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on" class="btn btn-light px-4 py-2 rounded-0">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="../assets/images/peakpx(72).jpg" class=" w-100" alt="pic">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-flex flex-column h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <h2 class="bg-dark bg-opacity-50 py-2 px-4">Nipsey Hussle</h2>
        <p class="bg-dark bg-opacity-50 py-2 px-4">Nipsey passed away and left us with a long-lasting legend, legacy and movement. We celebrate him and his memeory with his music.</p>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/search?gs_ssp=eJzj4tLP1TcwzasqKc42YPTizcssKE6tVMgoLS7OSQUAejkJUw&q=nipsey+hussle&rlz=1CAHUVK_enUS1057&oq=nipsey&aqs=chrome.1.0i355i433i512j46i433i512j69i57j0i131i433i512j0i433i512j46i433i512j69i61l2.1901j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on" class="btn btn-light px-4 py-2 rounded-0">Learn More</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```